page.type() works but locator.fill() times out, I'm trying to understand why
I tried using the playwright python locator.fill() method on a web element, and its timing out. I found another way to interact with an input element that works. I'm just trying to understand why.
html looks like this:


<div class="form-row">
<label class="required" for="id_username">Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" autofocus="" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" maxlength="150" required="" id="id_username">



This code times out on the fill command:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=os.environ.get("HEADLESS", "true") == "true")
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()
        page.get_by_role('input', name="username").fill('myUser')

*** playwright._impl._errors.TimeoutError: Locator.fill: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
Call log:
waiting for get_by_role("input", name="username")

but this code works:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=os.environ.get("HEADLESS", "true") == "true")
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()
        page.type('input[name="username"]', 'myUser')

I am just trying to understand why, I haven't found anything online about it. Maybe its a user error, but in case it isn't and someone else has this issue, now there's something.

Can you share the actual page, or a [mcve]? page.fill() looks for visibility/actionability, which isn't always achievable depending on the behavior of the specific site you're automating.

get_by_role accepts "textbox" as an input argument. input is an abstract superclass role. At the time of writing, here's the tuple of possible role arguments provided by the docs (in collapsible snippet for brevity):


const validRoles = [
"alert",
"alertdialog",
"application",
"article",
"banner",
"blockquote",
"button",
"caption",
"cell",
"checkbox",
"code",
"columnheader",
"combobox",
"complementary",
"contentinfo",
"definition",
"deletion",
"dialog",
"directory",
"document",
"emphasis",
"feed",
"figure",
"form",
"generic",
"grid",
"gridcell",
"group",
"heading",
"img",
"insertion",
"link",
"list",
"listbox",
"listitem",
"log",
"main",
"marquee",
"math",
"meter",
"menu",
"menubar",
"menuitem",
"menuitemcheckbox",
"menuitemradio",
"navigation",
"none",
"note",
"option",
"paragraph",
"presentation",
"progressbar",
"radio",
"radiogroup",
"region",
"row",
"rowgroup",
"rowheader",
"scrollbar",
"search",
"searchbox",
"separator",
"slider",
"spinbutton",
"status",
"strong",
"subscript",
"superscript",
"switch",
"tab",
"table",
"tablist",
"tabpanel",
"term",
"textbox",
"time",
"timer",
"toolbar",
"tooltip",
"tree",
"treegrid",
"treeitem"
];

console.log(validRoles);



Secondly, get_by_role uses the input's placeholder text or visible label name to locate the element by the optional name parameter. See Accessible Name docs on MDN:

For form elements like <textarea> and <input>, the accessible name comes from the associated <label> element. The association needs to be explicitly defined by setting the for attribute in the <label> element to match the form element's id. Alternatively, an implicit association is created when the form control is directly nested within the <label> element.

Minimally, by label:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright # 1.43.0


html = """
<label for="id_username">Username:</label>
<input id="id_username" />"""


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(html)
    page.get_by_role("textbox", name="Username:").fill("foobar")

Or by placeholder:
html = '<input placeholder="username" />'


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(html)
    page.get_by_role("textbox", name="username").fill("foobar")

If the element doesn't have a placeholder or label, you can use your standard CSS selector approach as a fallback.
I don't think the action (type versus fill) matters--the critical piece is whether you're using an aria role or a CSS selector to select the element. Using locators and .fill() is preferred over page.type(), which is deprecated:
page.locator('input[name="username"]').fill('myUser')

